# How to configure go-ethereum? (Config File)

Tags: go-ethereum, configuration

I setup an exchange with ethereum, I have installed ethereum [as documented here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-Instructions-for-Ubuntu).

But I can't find config file of the go-ethereum client, in bitcoin core it's `./bitcoin/bitcoin.conf`

Because i wanted create a connection to ethereum server. How do configure it?

Comment: There's nothing such as an "Ethereum Server". You become a part of the Ethereum network by running `geth`. Your system connects to other nodes and the public blockchain is automatically downloaded.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, there may be not such a conf file as you're looking for.
Read this:

> Ubuntu The below relates to installs compiled from source.
>   === C++ ===
>
> AlethZero ~/.ethereum/ (contains the blockchain state) ~/.web3
>   (contains your keys) ~/.config/ethereum/alethzero.conf (contains AZ
>   preferences)
>
> Eth ~/.ethereum/ (contains the blockchain state and keys, shares them
>   with alethzero) ~/.web3 (contains your keys, shares them with
>   alethzero)
>
> For both Eth and AlethZero, the DAG is stored in ~/.ethash
>
> === Go ===
>
> Geth: ~/.ethereum (contains the chain, as well as your keys are in the
>   /keystore subfolder) ~/.ethash (contains the DAG when mining)

From: https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/2114/where-are-my-config-files-go-and-cpp

If you need to set config some details maybe by using the command line options (https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options), or the JavaScript Console (https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/JavaScript-Console), or using the management API (https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs)

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can now. Here is an example: https://github.com/zhiyuan2007/sample-ethereum.toml/blob/master/geth.toml

`geth --configfile=config.toml`